# How do I stop WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 from removing XML header?

Tags: xml, xsd, wso2

I have an XML schema file starting with the following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I import the file to WSO2 Governance Registry (WSO2 G-REG) 4.5.3. When I later on retrieve the file using the WSO2 G-REG HTTP permalink to the content I get a file in which that line is removed.

What is happening? How can I prevent G-REG from removing that line?

Comment: what is the version you are using. I could upload a sample xml file (sample.xml)in 4.5.3 and gave the complete xml with the first line without a problem.

Comment: Good point. I have added the WSO G-REG version in the question. It is 4.5.3. Does your sample.xml contain an XML declaration similar to the one posted in the question?

Comment: Did you view the file from the browser? Can you try download the file and see? if that is there. (This is a pretty basic thing but i am out of clues.)

Comment: I both tried to view it in a browser, but I also downloaded it and in both cases the XML declaration is not there. The sample.xml that you uploaded did that one have an XML declaration (<?xml ...) before you uploaded it?